# PHP Team Fortress 2 Server Status always returns offline

Tags: php, status, steam

I am trying to integrate a server status on my homepage, a simple image system ( one is displayed when the server is on and other when the server is off ) but the current php code is always returning offline, when the server is online:

```
<?php

$ip = "173.208.81.98"; 
$port = "27015"; 

$sock = @fsockopen( $ip, $port, $num, $error, 1 );

if( !$sock ){


echo( "<img src='../assets/images/off2.png' style='width: 100%'>");
}

else( $sock ){


echo( "<img src='../assets/images/on2.png' style='width: 100%'>" );
fclose($sock);

}

?>
```

It's a Team Fortress 2 Server, in case it matters

Comment: Remove the `@` to see any error messages that may come up

Comment: Not the solution, but rather use if...else instead of those two ifs

Comment: @Pekka 웃 Says it could not connect to the ip

Comment: That's your problem then. What does it say exactly?

Comment: @Pekka 웃 Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to 173.208.81.98:27015 (Connection timed out) in /home/a5859910/public_html/status.php on line 112

Comment: Is it possible that the TF2 server declines connections who aren't game clients? Google.com:80 works for example.

Comment: @Sbls Tried with my website and works, tried with another game server and it doesn't, tried, tf2, cs:go & mc servers, none worked, but there are several sites with these statuses...

Comment: Source servers use UDP, so you need to prepend the IP with `udp://` in the `fsockopen` call.

Comment: @slugonamission i tried that and sadly it does not change the outcome :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why it works, but it seems to work with `stream_socket_client`. *Apparently not*

```
$ip = "173.208.81.98";
$port = 27015;
if(@stream_socket_client("tcp://$ip:$port") !== false) {
    echo 'online';
} else {
    echo 'offline';
}
```

---

E:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

there is a list of commands you can send to the server. However there is no online option. I think you still need to check if stream_socket_client is false. If it is false, the server definitly is down. It is possible, that you can reach the server but it is listed as unavailable. I don't know how Valve handles those things. I noticed that it isn't congruent to the list at firepoweredgaming.com.

So, basically the following don't really suit you. But maybe you can use it.

```
    function server($ip, $port) {
        $command = "\377\377\377\377TSource Engine Query\0";
        $socket = stream_socket_client("udp://$ip:$port");
        fwrite($socket, $command);  // Send the command
        $JunkHead = fread($socket,4);

            fread($socket, 1); // Always equal to 0x49, Header chunk
            $return['protocol'] = ord(fread($socket, 1));
            $return['name'] = getNextString($socket);
            $return['map'] = getNextString($socket);
            $return['folder'] = getNextString($socket);
            $return['game'] = getNextString($socket);
            $return['id'] = ord(fread($socket, 2));
            $return['players'] = ord(fread($socket, 1));
            $return['max_players'] = ord(fread($socket, 1));
            $return['bots'] = ord(fread($socket, 1));
            $return['server_type'] = fread($socket, 1); // [d]edicated, [l] non-dedicated, [p] SourceTV
            $return['environment'] = fread($socket, 1); // [l]inux, [w]indows or [m]ac
            $return['visibility'] = ord(fread($socket, 1)); // 1==private
            $return['vac'] = ord(fread($socket, 1)); // 1==secure
            $return['version'] = getNextString($socket);

        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * freads until \0 is found. Nullterminated string.
    */
    function getNextString($socket) {
        $str = '';
        while(($read = fread($socket, 1)) != "\0") {
            $str .= $read;
        }
        return $str;
    }
```

I have a function called server which reads data into an array. (You can print it with `print_r(server('173.208.81.98', 27015))`). I used `ord()` to get numbers out of the ascii, because php reads the socket as ascii.

Comment: This doesn't work at all, it shows it is online even if the server is offline

Comment: I can't test it with an TF server. But if I switch the IP or even port it shows me offline. Currently offline for your server!

Comment: my server is offline for the moment i am using these:https://firepoweredgaming.com/forums/page/servers_live to test the status, the ip above is from the first one, that is online

Comment: Results to the same status for me.

Comment: even the ones offline? i guess i must have messed up somewhere then

Comment: Maybe look into those scripts: http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/4441
I can clean them up if you want me to :)

Comment: I would appreciate that very much since im new to this language:) if there is any sort of reward on this site i can give you for that let me know:) found something interesting: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query-Class   but tf2 servers do not support the ping command anymore

Comment: Edited out. Put my own code in. Doesn't solve your online/offline problem though. You could workaround it with checking if there are 0 users on the server.

Comment: Thank you i have been looking in some other docs, if i find a solution ill post the answer, but that method with the 0 users online is not really reliable since some times of the day the server will be with 0 players on

Comment: Hey again, can you help me out here?? im trying toturn this data http://pastebin.com/dziQzXt7 into the html text "Online players: players/max players | Bots: number ofbots | map: map name"

Comment: $return holds the array with all the infos.  You can output it like that:
`echo "Online players: {$return['players']} / {$return['max_players']} | Bots: {$return['bots']} | map: {$return['map']}";`

Answer (score 0):

A 1 second connect timeout is not very long. Network lag can be enough to trigger that even when the host/port is valid. I would suggest using at least 2.5 - 5 seconds instead.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $ip = "173.208.81.98"; 
    $port = "27015"; 
    $sock = @fsockopen( $ip, $port, $num, $error, 5 );

    if( !$sock ){
        echo( "<img src='../assets/images/off2.png' style='width: 100%'>");
    } else {
        echo( "<img src='../assets/images/on2.png' style='width: 100%'>" );
        fclose($sock);
    }
?>
```

Comment: no luck, increased to 10 and it still returns the offline picture

Comment: http://173.208.81.98:27015 server is offline! Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 173.208.81.98:27015

Comment: it is online, im am playing on it right now. Tried other ips and the result is the same